# Solve inexact ODE with integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, integrating-factor

We have ODE  $$0=-\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}y'$$  where  $(x,y)\in]0,\infty[\times]0,\infty[$.

It's **inexact**, since$$\frac{dP(x,y)}{dy}=\frac{x}{y^2}\neq-\frac{y}{x^2}=\frac{dM(x,y)}{dx}$$

I can only find one integrating factor $R(x,y)=xy$, then we get $$\frac{dP(x,y)\cdot{R(x,y)}}{dy}=-\frac{dx^2}{dy}=0=\frac{dy^2}{dx}=\frac{dM(x,y)\cdot{R(x,y)}}{dx}$$

Then I can solve this problem correctly.  What I am not quite sure about is are we allowed to get **$0$** as result after derivation at x and y. And is there another way to find a better integrating factor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are $M$ and $P$?

Comment: We use it for P(x,y)+M(x,y)y'=0 and verify whether it is exact or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}y'=0$$
The integrating factor is $\mu(xy)=xy$:
$$-{x^2}dx+{y^2}dy=0$$
Then the DE is exact since:
$$\partial_y (-x^2)=\partial_x(y^2)=0$$
Then integrate:
$$-{x^2}dx+{y^2}dy=0$$
$${x^3}-{y^3}=C$$

---

$$P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$$
When you have:
$$\partial_y (P(x,y))=0 \implies P=P(x)$$
$$\partial_x (Q(x,y))=0 \implies Q=Q(y)$$
the DE is exact anf also separable:
$$P(x)dx+Q(y)dy=0$$
$$\int P(x)dx=-\int Q(y)dy$$

Comment: Yes, that's what I had. Do you mean that my integrating factor is allowed?

Comment: Yes your answer is correct @Malik  anf zero is allowed

Comment: and we get $y=\sqrt[3]{x^3-c}$, thanks!

Comment: Yes @Malik You're welcome